# How to refresh user attributes in id token, after they are updated in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm updating some of the user's custom attributes (extension attributes) in AD B2C using `PATCH` method and url `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userid`

The problem is that in app, I don't see any changes in response token until I to sign out and sign in again.

So even I get new token after old one is expired in new token still there is no updated changes.
Anyone had similar problem?
How to refresh users attribute in id token without signing out from app?

Here is image with old data `extension_CompanyName`. This field  is changed to Ruid but in token I still see old data Microsoft 4444

[image]

Comment: B2C doesn't currently refresh claims in the refresh token - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016498/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-propogate-new-user-claims-to-the-access-token

Comment: Thanks @HardRock and please let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it's little bit disappointing that B2C doesn't support this feature, hopefully they will correct it in some future releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392633/azure-ad-b2c-access-token-claims-do-not-update-after-refreshing-token).  **Azure AD B2C**  the `claim` will not be updated after the token is refreshed, but I think Microsoft should improve the problem.

So, you can post your idea on [Azure AD User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=160596).